# How to set parameters to score function in sklearn SelectKBest ()

Tags: python, class, machine-learning, syntax, scikit-learn

I'm using the `SelectKBest()` class for feature selection in sklearn. `SelectKBest()` can take a callable score function as an input. In this case I would like to use `mutual_info_regression` as the score function. `mutual_info_regression` can take a few parameters which I would like to set myself. For example, I would like to set the `random_state = 0`. The problem is I'm not sure how to pass parameters into the score function since the score function is itself a parameter in `SelectKBest()`. Obviously something like `SelectKBest(score_func = mutual_info_classif(random_state=0))` won't work because the `mutal_info_classif` function would be called directly. I feel like this is probably a very basic question about python classes but I can't seem to find anything addressing what I'm looking for. Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create another function which calls mutual_info_regression and pass it instead:

```
def my_score(X, y):
    return mutual_info_regression(X, y, random_state=0)

SelectKBest(score_func=my_score)
```

Python standard library provides an useful helper for creating such functions - it is called [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). It allows to create functions with some parameters pre-set; instead of "manual" my_score definition you can write

```
from functools import partial
my_score = partial(mutual_info_regression, random_state=0)
SelectKBest(score_func=my_score)
```

Of course, you can also pass `partial` directly, which gets you very close to your example:

```
from functools import partial
SelectKBest(score_func=partial(mutual_info_classif, random_state=0))
```

Comment: Ah yes I see. Thanks a ton!